# SCSS if directive: how to pass multiple variables?

Tags: sass, mixins

How would I write this code so I check for both the truthiness of $text-shadows as well as $shadows?

```
.btn {
  @if $text-shadows {
    @include text-shadow-black;
  }
  @if $shadows {
    @include shadow-white;
  }
 }
```

To be clear, what I want to achieve is this without nesting:

```
.btn {
  @if $text-shadows {
    @if $shadows {
      @include text-shadow-black;
    }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `and` keyword:

```
.btn {
  @if $text-shadows and $shadows {
      @include text-shadow-black;
  }
}
```